# How do i load instances from files to many lists?

Tags: java, eclipse, list, file, serialization

i'm trying to save my lists in file named "Unidade de saúde",
and i write in the file each list.
And i think it is working because when i save something it appears on the file.

i have Serializable in every class now so i think it is working fine.

```
package entidades;

//imports

public class Gravar {

    public static void gravarArquivoBinario(List<Profissional> profissional, List<Utente> utente, List<Familia> familia, List<Associa> asso, List<Cuidados> cui) {
        File arq = new File("Unidade de saúde.txt");
        try {
            arq.delete();
            arq.createNewFile();

            ObjectOutputStream objOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(arq));
            objOutput.writeObject(profissional);
            objOutput.writeObject(utente);
            objOutput.writeObject(familia);
            objOutput.writeObject(asso);
            objOutput.writeObject(cui);
            objOutput.close();

        }catch(IOException erro) {
            System.out.printf("Erro: %s", erro.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And now i'm trying to load to my lists but it does load them to the program i do i do that??

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<Object> lerArquivoBinario(List<Profissional> profissional, List<Utente> utente, List<Familia> familia, List<Associa> asso, List<Cuidados> cui) {
        List<Profissional> listaPro = new ArrayList<Profissional>();
        List<Utente> listaUte = new ArrayList<Utente>();
        List<Familia> listaFam = new ArrayList<Familia>();
        List<Associa> listaAss = new ArrayList<Associa>();
        List<Cuidados> listaCui = new ArrayList<Cuidados>();
          try {
            File arq = new File("Unidade de saúde.txt");
            if (arq.exists()) {
               ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(arq));
               listaPro = (List<Profissional>)objInput.readObject();
               listaUte = (List<Utente>)objInput.readObject();
               listaFam = (List<Familia>)objInput.readObject();
               listaAss = (List<Associa>)objInput.readObject();
               listaCui = (List<Cuidados>)objInput.readObject();
               objInput.close();
            }
          } catch(IOException erro1) {
              System.out.printf("Erro: %s", erro1.getMessage());
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException erro2) {
              System.out.printf("Erro: %s", erro2.getMessage());
          }

          return(listaPro);
    }
}
```

And i know the return(listaPro) is wrong but i don't know how to return many lists.

Comment: Print the stack trace of the exception, and post it. It tells you what is wrong and where.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write in files if the specified type implements `Serializable` . 
`List` is just an interface and doesn't extend the `Serializable`, are you sure that the profissional,utente etc. implements it?

Comment: but every class has to have it? or is just the main??

Comment: Every object that you want to serialize must be serializable. If it's not, it can't be serialized, by definition. So the lists, all the objects they contain, all the object the contained objects contain, etc. etc. must be serializable.

Comment: I have updated the code and the text, but i still can't put it to work.

Comment: By can't put it to work, do you mean you can't find the "Unidade de saúde.txt" ?